# PhpStorm combine multiple Predefined Live Template functions

Tags: phpstorm, live-templates

I have a project where my files are in "lisp-case" (hyphen delimited) and I would like to use the filename as a variable in a live template, but it must be converted to CamelCase first.

I found out that you can set the expression `fileNameWithoutExtension()` under "Edit Template Variables" and there is also a function called `camelCase()` which should be able to turn my filenames into CamelCase. But I cannot figure out how to combine those two. I tried doing `camelCase(fileNameWithoutExtension())` but that does not work, unfortunately.

Is it possible to achieve this some other way?

[image]

Comment: Screenshot please -- works fine here: it converts `abc-def-hed.php` file name into `abcDefHed`

Comment: Thanks. I've added a screenshot. If I try to wrap fileNameWithoutExtension() inside camelCase() and press enter to save the entry the window is closed but the change is not saved.

Comment: Also, when editing the field it's rendered like a select box which is kind of weird. Maybe it's a bug in this specific version. I'm on PhpStorm 10.0.4 for Mac. There is an update available I'll try that out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> camelCase(fileNameWithoutExtension())

It's a correct syntax.

> Is it possible to achieve this some other way?

Please ensure that `Skip if defined` checkbox is checked for this variable.

[image]

> If I try to wrap `fileNameWithoutExtension()` inside `camelCase()` and press enter to save the entry the window is closed but the change is not saved

It's an IDE bug (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132965 -- supposed to be fixed in current 2017.1.x version).

In any case: either press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before leaving the field ... or click on `OK` button straight away (you may then reopen this window to do further changes).

> Also, when editing the field it's rendered like a select box which is kind of weird. Maybe it's a bug in this specific version. I'm on PhpStorm 10.0.4 for Mac.

Not a Mac user here .. but it is an editable drop-down box indeed (it lists all possible functions).

[image]

Comment: I did not get a list of possibilities in the dropdown. But I updated to the latest version and it was fixed :)

Comment: Also, I tried all kinds of combinations of pressing enter inside or outside the field or simply pressing ok straight away and that did not save the contents of the field. But now with the most recent version it works as expected - I also get options when I open the dropdown.